# Textarea startswith function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, startswith

I am trying to apply starts with function on textarea, but obviously I am doing something wrong. I don't understand javascript, so I am sorry for obvious mistakes or problems. At least I tried what seemed logical to me... Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/235/

HTML:

```js
$("textarea").bind(function () {
  if ($(this).startsWith("Hello") {
      $(".kuk").show();
  }
  else {
   $(".kuk").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.kuk {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<button class="kuk">Clear</button>
```

And what if someone pastes the text "Hello" with right click of mouse? How to recognize that action too?

Comment: `$(this).val().startsWith("Hello")`

Comment: also you never close the if statement with `)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/240/

Comment: But what if someone pastes the text "Hello" with right click of mouse? How to recognize that action too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `val()` then use `startsWith()`. Additionally you need to bind proper event handler. Here I have used `keyup`

```
$("textarea").on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().startsWith("Hello")) {
        $(".kuk").show();
    } else {
        $(".kuk").hide();
    }
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/236/)

Comment: Yes it is correct :) seems prety obvious right now, Thank You very much, and I have one more question, is there some easy way to write multiple parameters? Something like: if .startWith("This" or "This" or "This")) ?

Comment: @user7176800, `$(this).val().startsWith("Hello") || $(this).val().startsWith("this")`

Comment: But what if someone pastes the text "Hello" with right click of mouse? How to recognize that action too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to bind an `event` also you need to get `val` to check whether it `startswith hello` or not.

```
 $("textarea").bind('keyup',function () {
       if ($(this).val().startsWith("Hello")) {
          $(".kuk").show();
       }
       else {
          $(".kuk").hide();
       }
    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/237/) is jsfiddle

Comment: But what if someone pastes the text "Hello" with right click of mouse? How to recognize that action too?

Comment: @user7176800 handle paste event for that.

Comment: I used just 'input' and it register both- paste and type too!

Answer (score 0):

I made jsfiddle for those wondering which code I am using right now. I added few kinds of input options and now it works in chrome as well.

[final fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/246/)

```
$("textarea").bind('change keyup paste blur input',function () {
   if ($(this).val().startsWith("Hello") || $(this).val().startsWith("HELLO") || $(this).val().startsWith("hello")) {
      $(".kuk").show();
   }
   else {
      $(".kuk").hide();
   }
});
```